# How to change position of \affmark while using authblk package

Tags: authblk

In the following MWE, I want to change the position of affiliation marks (1,2,3,...) to appear just after the author name and everything like the footnote mark and Orchid ID logo should be placed after the affiliation marks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[blocks]{authblk}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{lime}{HTML}{A6CE39}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\orcidicon}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[lime, fill=lime] (0,0) 
    circle [radius=0.16] 
    node[white] {{\fontfamily{qag}\selectfont \tiny ID}};
    \draw[white, fill=white] (-0.0625,0.095) 
    circle [radius=0.007];
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \hspace{-2mm}
}
\newcommand{\orcid}[1]{\href{https://orcid.org/#1}{\orcidicon}}

\title{AuthBlk Test}
\author[1]{Author A \footnote{Corresponding author: Author}\orcid{0000-0002-1825-0097}}
\author[2]{Author B\orcid{0000-0002-1825-0097}}
\author[3]{Author C\orcid{0000-0002-1825-0097}}
\affil[1]{Department of Subject1, Example University1, Example Country1 }
\affil[2]{Department of Subject2, Example University2, Example Country2 }
\affil[3]{Department of Subject3, Example University3, Example Country3 }

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

**This is what I have:**
[image: AuthBlk Problem LaTeX]

**This is what I want to achieve:**
[image: AuthBlk target word]

Comment: Your MWE doesn't want to compile for me: "Unknown option `block' for package `authblk'." and "! Undefined control sequence....\orcid"

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Sorry, my bad, there was a typo, I have fixed it and have also added \orcid command code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key proved to be looking at how `authblk` redefined the `\maketitle` process.  In the end, the fix was pretty simple.  Redefine `\orcid` to `\rlap` an `\extragap` along with the `\href`'ed `\orcidicon`, which would push the icon to the right of the footnote/affiliation marks.  But the comma would then lay under the icon.

So, `authblk` provides macros for the comma typesetting: `\Authsep` for all authors except the last, and `\Authands` for the last.  Thus, to both of these, I just had to add `\extragap` and a `\phantom` of `\orcidicon` before setting the comma.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[blocks]{authblk}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{lime}{HTML}{A6CE39}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\orcidicon}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[lime, fill=lime] (0,0) 
    circle [radius=0.16] 
    node[white] {{\fontfamily{qag}\selectfont \tiny ID}};
    \draw[white, fill=white] (-0.0625,0.095) 
    circle [radius=0.007];
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \hspace{-2mm}
}
\def\extragap{~\,}
\newcommand{\orcid}[1]{%
  \rlap{\extragap\href{https://orcid.org/#1}{\orcidicon}}}

\title{AuthBlk Test}
\author[1]{Author A\footnote{Corresponding author: Author}\orcid{0000-0002-1825-0097}}
\author[2]{Author B\orcid{0000-0002-1825-0097}}
\author[3]{Author C\orcid{0000-0002-1825-0097}}
\affil[1]{Department of Subject1, Example University1, Example Country1 }
\affil[2]{Department of Subject2, Example University2, Example Country2 }
\affil[3]{Department of Subject3, Example University3, Example Country3 }

\def\Authsep{\phantom{\extragap\orcidicon}, }
\def\Authands{\phantom{\extragap\orcidicon}, and }
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

A slightly more visually pleasing comma separation might be achieved with this alternative:

```
\def\extragap{\kern3pt}
\newcommand{\orcid}[1]{%
  \rlap{\extragap\extragap\href{https://orcid.org/#1}{\orcidicon}}}
```

[image]

Comment: redefining `\Authsep` and `\Authands` is indeed a smart way to do this. I like that. I was wondering if there is a way to prioritize the affiliation mark towards the left of all other things e.g. here footnote mark (`*`) or a mark created by `\thanks{}` command.

Comment: @aaryan As to the footnotemark, if you, starting with my original MWE, define `\def\extragap{~~}` and then use `\author[1]{Author A\rlap{\phantom{\,\extragap\orcidicon}\footnote{Corresponding author: Author}}\orcid{0000-0002-1825-0097}\,}`, you achieve the desired output...however, the input is starting to get quite messy.

Comment: For anyone wondering why the above solution doesn’t work — and happens to have a *two* author article — you also need to redefine `\Authand`, without an `s`.